# Js: It is a program to make a kind of bill

Tags: javascript, json, request, variable-assignment

A shop will give discount of 10% if the cost of purchased quantity is more than 1000.

Ask the user for the quantity. Suppose, one unit will cost 100.

Judge and print total cost for user. Ask for name phone number as well as bill amount

```js
const bill_maker = () => {
  const bill_format = {
    name_customer: prompt("Enter the customer's name"),
    phone_number: Number(prompt("Enter the customer's phone number")),
    total_bill_amount: Number(prompt("Enter the bill amount"))
  }
  
  // Conditions 
  if (bill_format.total_bill_amount > 1000) {
    return (`${bill_format.total_bill_amount}.Oh! You have 10% discount so you have to pay:` (bill_format.total_bill_amount / 1000) * 100)
  } else {
    return `${bill_format.total_bill_amount}. You have to pay`
    `${bill_format.name_customer} Do visit us again!`
  }
}

console.log(bill_maker())
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Copy/pasting a homework assignment and pasting some code doesn't tell us what problem you are having.

Comment: Please take care when selecting tags. Most of yours appear to be irrelevant. Certainly there's no JSON and this has nothing to do with AnyLogic.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because your template literal syntax is invalid. In each case you've split them without declaring new variables for the second part.

To fix the problem, merges the template literals in both sides of your `if` condition:

```js
const bill_maker = () => {
  const bill_format = {
    name_customer: prompt("Enter the customer's name"),
    phone_number: Number(prompt("Enter the customer's phone number")),
    total_bill_amount: Number(prompt("Enter the bill amount"))
  }
  
  console.log(bill_format.total_bill_amount);
  
  // Conditions 
  if (bill_format.total_bill_amount > 1000) {
    return `${bill_format.total_bill_amount}.Oh! You have 10% discount so you have to pay: ${(bill_format.total_bill_amount / 1000) * 100}`;
  } else {
    return `${bill_format.total_bill_amount}. You have to pay: ${bill_format.name_customer}. Do visit us again!`
  }
}

console.log(bill_maker())
```

Comment: Sorry thanks for the help but i could not exactly get you

Comment: if possible can you fix the code and show would be great! Thanks in anticipation

Comment: This code does fix the problem...

Comment: ? which could plss help i really need it plss

Comment: The code in the answer, written above. Click the 'Run code snippet' button to see it working.

Comment: thanks a lot sir i am using the StackOverflow for the first time so I was bit struggling thanks for helping me patiently